# Using jQuery to add a fixed position to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the effect of an `div` scrolling until it reaches the top and just stays there.

I have achieved this with:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">this is nav</div>
    <div id="mooey">
    <div id="theFixed" style="position:fixed; background-color:red">SOMETHING</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mooey {
    background: green;
    min-height:250px;
    margin-top:300px;
```

}

```
#nav {
    background:#000000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top", Math.max(100, 300 - $(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

What I want to do, Instead of stating that the div `theFixed` is fixed in the style in the HTML. I was wondering if there was a way of applying this using the code.

Reason being is that if the script isn't enables or fails for whatever reason - I want the `theFixed` div to scroll along with the `mooey` div rather than be stuck in the middle of the page.

You can see what I have done here:

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/4J5aj/7/

Any ideas for this?

Comment: What about `$("#theFixed").css("position","fixed");` ?

Comment: @Chris, Suzi is asking to make the page work in the case that the Javascript fails to load, so the solution can't include Javascript.

Comment: What i understand is, she wants to set the fixed property in the code so that if JavaScript is disabled, the element won't be fixed and scroll along with the content.

Comment: Yes you understood it right. I wanted the css style only to exist if javascript was running so if javascript fails- no style. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#theFixed').css('position','fixed');` to pin it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#FixedElement").css("position","fixed");
});
</script>
```